# Javascript putting an image in a span

Tags: javascript, image, html

My code, which should put an image in the `<span>` is this:

```
document.getElementById("f_name_mark").innerText = "<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>";
```

However, the output is `<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>` as a text string.

Is it that you can't put an image in a `<span>`?

Comment: A `span` is an inline -- not even block-inline -- element (by default). I am not sure if it is permissible to put an `img` in a `span` either because of HTML (certain restrictions based on elements) or CSS rules (certain restrictions based on CSS attributes?). I would like to see both of these issues addressed in an answer, even if accepted by browsers.

Comment: `span` is an inline element.  `img` is a block level element.  block level elements should not go in inline elements but most browsers will let you anyway.  For compatibility it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `InnerHTML` instead of `innerText`

[Innerhtml and Innertext properties](http://www.how2dev.com/innerhtml-and-innertext-properties/)

Unlike InnerText, though, InnerHtml lets you work with HTML rich text and doesn't automatically encode and decode text. In other words, InnerText retrieves and sets the content of the tag as plain text, whereas InnerHtml retrieves and sets the same content but in HTML format

Span is inline element and image is block element, you can set the display of span element to block or use div to handle it.

```
document.getElementById("f_name_mark").innerHTML = "<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>";
```

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTML` is there for a reason :) Try

```
document.getElementById("f_name_mark").innerHTML = "<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `innerHTML` or `innerText`. Instead, create the img element, set the attributes and append them to your span.

```
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

img.setAttribute('src', 'images/icons/tick.png');
img.setAttribute('class', 'mark');

document.getElementById("f_name_mark").appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("f_name_mark").innerHTML = "<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `innerHTML` attribute, not `innerText`.  It will be parsed and displayed as HTML, whereas `innerText` will just display as text.